# How to bind variables into websocket route paths using Spark Web Framework?

Tags: java, path, websocket, routes, spark-java

I'm, trying to implement a websocket server using Spark (a java web framework). I'm using the version 2.3 that has added support for it.

There's some way to bind variables into route paths just like http routes?

e.g. /chat/:city

I want to create conversation channels among users. If it's possible, how can I make it work and how can I retrieve the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add ?userId=somekey to the end of path on your client side. Example would be to initialize your websocket path to Spark.websocket("/chat") (server-side obvi.) . Then have your client hit the URL with /chat?userId=blah. From the server side you'll receive a connection for the socket. From there simply grab the incoming URI from the socket connection and use the String userKey = session.getRemote().getQuery() method to pull of the field. May have to do a user.split("=")[1] to get the value

Comment: Thank you @stackoverflow. :)

Answer (score 1):

(stackoverflow's answer didn't worked for me, but pointed me in the right direction):

I managed to get the parameters this way:

```
@OnWebSocketConnect
void onConnect(Session sockSession) throws Exception {
    Map<String, List<String>> params = sockSession.upgradeRequest.parameterMap;
    if(params != null && params.containsKey("city")) {
         // As the parameter's value is a List, we use 'get(0)'
         String city = params.get("city").get(0);
         ...
    }
    ...
}
```